# C# use date from serial port in mainprogram

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I need to read data from COM port. The data comes from Arduino, it needs to be parsed by the C# program and do certain things on the host PC. I can read the data, but only with endless "while true" loop. which is blocking the form and other tasks to be executed. So currently it looks like that:

```
while (true) {
                oneLine = myPort.ReadLine();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(display_data_Event));

                // TBD: add analysis of data from port
                // TBD: execute according to data from Arduino
            }
```

the handler:

```
        private void display_data_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string curr_time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        port_in_TextBox.AppendText(curr_time + "       " + oneLine + "\n");
    }
```

So I can display the data to a textbox, but not use it with my main program.

How can I use the "one line" string only when the event occurs, instead of the "while true"?
I tried calling functions from the handler - I guess it failed because it is another thread. So perhaps the problem is how to share the string from one thread to another.

Comment: You have a crossthread issue and need to use Invoke.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks, but I still miss something. Is the role of the textbox here to act like a buffer? If so, how do I read the first line in this "fifo" and how I eliminate lines I already fetched? I was thinking the solution would be some kind of a buffer, which one thread writes into (the com port handler) and the main program is triggered to read line after line when available.

Comment: I would setup the text box as multiline.  The textbox is filled with a single string.  So you can use the string method IndexOf("\n") to get the end of line and the remove characters by using SubString(start index) to remove items.  So if you want to remove the first 20 items : line = line.Substring(20).  Or line = line.Remove(20);  I think this is better than to put the lines into a List<string> and fill the text box from the List.   All methods will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am lost, here is the core program:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8

Now, the question is do you need one input or many. If the former, add `AutoResetEvent` so the main program will be blocked, and reading the data will signal it to unblock. Or if there are many lines add your "main" action in the event just after you read each line.